# How to change wrap order in materialize grid

Tags: html, grid, materialize

I have a problem with wraping materialize grid. 
Now its look like:

[A][B][C][D],

and when i resize to small - <600px it look like:

[A][B]

[C][D]

but i want to look like:

[A][C]

[B][D]

Does anyone know how I can change it?

```
 <div class="col s12 l9" id="foo">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6 m3" id="one"></div>
            <div class="col s6 m3" id="two"></div>
            <div class="col s6 m3" id="three"></div>
            <div class="col s6 m3" id="four"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some hacks with grid and you can have what you wanted.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            <div class="col m6 s12">A</div>
            <div class="col m6 s12">B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6">
            <div class="col m6 s12">C</div>
            <div class="col m6 s12">D</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```